# Why can't I use variable inside @include in my Sass loop?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

So let's say I have the following mixins:

```
@mixin type-h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
        
@mixin type-h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
        
@mixin type-h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now I created utility classes:

```
.type-h1 {
  @include type-h1;
}

.type-h2 {
  @include type-h2;
}

.type-h3 {
  @include type-h3;
}
```

All good so far. Now I would like to simplify my code and generate the utility classes using Sass loops. This is what I have:

```
$variable: 1, 2, 3;
@each $value in $variable {
  .type-h#{$value} {
    @include type-h$variable;
  }
}
```

Anyone has an idea why this loop doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create map with variables:

```
$vars: (1: 36px, 2: 28px, 3: 24px);
```

Then combine mixins into one:

```
@mixin types($value) {
  font-size: $value;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

And finally you can generate your utilities by:

```
@each $size, $value in $vars {
  .type-h#{$size} {
    @include types($value);
  }
}
```

[Here is link to Codepen.io with example](https://codepen.io/yaroslav-trach/pen/XWzWvPL)